# YUM: Upgrade a package from a different repo

Tags: yum

Say I have two repos: repoa and repob. I installed a package 3.1 ver from repoa. I have a newer version 3.2 in repob.

How could I upgrade the package from repob? I tried to yum upgrade, but looks it always stick to the original repo - repoa, and didn't look at the package in repob at all. I can use 'yum provides' to get the package information from two repose, but only repoa looks recognised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several things such as change the priority higher for repob, temporarily remove the repoa, but none of them working.

I guess I need to remove it then do reinstallation from repob.

Comment: Finally what I did is: yum remove package first; then remove repoa from yum.repo.d; then reinstall the package from repob.